# How to check programmatically if a new screen is fully loaded after a click event in Android?

Tags: android, testing, android-uiautomator

I am running an auto test framework based on UIAutomator. While performing test steps, I wish to know when a new screen in completely loaded after a click event has occurred e.g. a button click.

Currently, I have added 2 seconds wait for the new screen to load but it is not efficient strategy.

I want to handle this case in my test framework and remove the requirement to explicitly wait.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [UiDevice.waitForIdle()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/uiautomator/UiDevice.html#waitforidle) or any of the other `wait*` methods depending on your case.

Answer (score 0):

Use this on the parent view:

```
parentView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {  }
```

This could be what you need.

Comment: I guess the idea is not to change the app